# Max-height not being set when it encloses a grid in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, aspxgridview

This question may have been asked a lot of times, but all the solutions were a fail(for me).

I'm enclosing a grid inside a div whose css is

```
 .Div 
    {
    max-height : 500px;
    overflow-x : auto ;
    overflow-y : auto;
    }
```

but, this doesnt work as the scroll for the vertical scroll always appears no matter whatever the height.
If i explicitly use a height property, then the scroll is working as functioned. but, doesnt when used with a max-height as i do not want to waste space for the  " div" if it encloses a grid having less no of data.

please help me out..!

I read somewhere that IE may be causing some problems if its IE8, but i'm having IE9.

Answer (score 0):

try `overflow: auto;` instead of `overflow-x` and `overflow-y`. It works in my projects.